# Simple way to zip large files through SSH commands

Tags: ssh

I have a folder Backissues/ in the root directory. the folder size is much higher which is about 132G. if i run the command **`zip -r backissue.zip Backissues/`** it takes too much time and returns some sort of disconnection after few hours. you can assume my knowledge is  not good in the SSH commands. just following through few tutorial get the task done. either if it can possible to split the folders into splitted files. I tried to do the zip to folder that contains not much files e.g. around 250m. that works perfectly and am able to download the files and re-use it someone where else. i'm in the shared hosting environment

**the folder is organized as 1991 1992 1993**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really an ssh question; the reason ssh is an issue here is because you have timeouts due to the action taking so much time.

Your main problem, the timeouts, is fixed by using background and nohup. Instead of executing `zip -r backissue.zip Backissues/`, you execute

```
nohup zip -r backissue.zip Backissues/ &
```

This does two things: the trailing `&` makes the zip process execute in the background, and the `nohup` disconnects the zip process from the connection you are using so that your ssh disconnecting will not interrupt the execution of the `zip` process. As long as your connection stays open, you can use the `jobs` bash command to manage the background zip command, but once you log off or your ssh connection breaks and you have to reconnect, you will have to check your process using `ps` or `top`, and the output in the file `nohup.out` that the `nohup` command creates. You do have to do that, remembering that the job may still be running in the background, because if you restart a process when another one is still executing you may run into needless problems.

I have two improvements on the above.

Using this command instead:

```
nohup bash -c "zip -r backissue.zip Backissues/ && touch backissue.finished" &
```

will leave you a tell-tale file that guarantees that the long-running zip operation finished correctly. Otherwise you have to rely on an error showing up in `nohup.out`, or `zip` only renaming the output file to its intended name when the process completes successfully.

You can in any case use the `zip` command's functionality to split output files into pieces, but I suppose you have many back issues. An improvement would be that instead of making one zip file of everything, you make one zip file for every back issue (assuming that your goal is to reduce space, and not to simply get a single file). This breaks the work into distinct parts that can be executed separately and would fail separately. It is also better practice: when you have a new back issue you will not need to redo the whole archive, and when you need access to a back issue, you only have to unzip the one you need. To do this, of course, you need to know how the Backissues folder is structured.

You add that (if I understand correctly) the Backissues folder is organized like this:

```
Backissues/1991
Backissues/1992
Backissues/1993
...
Backissues/2019
```

That means that if you instead write `year=1991 ; nohup zip -r Backissues.$year.zip Backissues/$year/ &` and repeat for all the years, waiting for the previous one to finish so you don't overload your server, you will get one zip file per year, which should be manageable without splitting the files further.

It can get more complicated, of course. As an example you can make use of a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d Backissues ] ; then
    echo Move to correct folder >&2
    exit 1
fi

mkdir -p Backissues.compressed

cd Backissues

for year in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ; do
    zipfile="../Backissues.compressed/$year.zip"
    if [ ! -f $zipfile ] ; then
        zip -r $zipfile $year && echo "Compressed $year successfully"
    fi
done
```

This script can be executed at any time, except that once made, a yearly archive will not be recreated automatically.

Someone competent in shell script programming would be able to customize this to your operational needs (only archiving one year at a time, not making an archive of the current year until the last issue is published or else updating the relevant archive(s) with the latest issue(s), deleting the originals to save space once one is totally certain that the archive is correct, copying backups to some safe storage -- on S3 Glacier Deep Archive your 132 GB would cost you less than USD 2.00 per year, doing all this automatically...)

Comment: that is the guide. have much understood with your explanation for dummy like me. the last paragraph is important to consider as this is too large files and it has to be in parts and each time i can not archive the whole back issue folder again and again.

Comment: @WaqasSaeed How is your Backissues folder organized? You can edit that into your question.

Comment: am able to understand that command nohup zip -r backissue.zip Backissues/ & and works for me. if some process that can individually compress each folder without putting load on the CPU. then it will be more greater. I can feel might you are also have something in your mind

Comment: `nohup bash -c "zip -r backissue.zip Backissues/ && touch backissue.finished" &
` how to get it stop or check if that is working? @Law29

Comment: Seems like you have thirty years of data, I understand your wish to back that up! I've expanded my answer, but I feel that you may want to find someone local to help you make certain of all this.

Comment: If you have not disconnected, use `jobs` to see the process, and if there is only one, the command `fg` will return the process to the foreground where Control-C will kill it. If you have (been) disconnected, use `ps auxwww | grep -v grep | grep zip` to find it and the `kill` command to stop it (you'll find how to do that in other answers here).

Comment: Thanks a lot you have really solved my problem. am able to recover almost 130gb of data from server to server migration. it is great honor to meet a expert like you. the way explained it is good to teach someone who has not much SSH knowledge.

Comment: Is it possible to queue the process with X number of running the process in backgournd with some bg command to linux SSH. individually.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the power of your server. If it is powerful enough then running processes in parallel will finish the work faster, if it is not powerful enough then it will be slower and may even prevent other services from working correctly. You have the command above, followed by "waiting for the previous one to finish so you don't overload your server".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your SSH connection is timing out due to no data being sent for an extended period. You might be able to prevent this by telling your SSH client to send a keepalive packet when the connection is idle.

The exact way you set this option depends on which SSH client you are using. For example, with OpenSSH you can say:

```
$ ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=25 your.server.address
```

This will send a keepalive every 25 seconds while the connection is idle to prevent it from disconnecting. This is documented in [the ssh_config man page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ServerAliveInterval).

Comment: This is an excellent recommendation that will help prevent timeouts. I prefer my answer as I eliminate the ill effects of timeouts and let you disconnect from the server, but this this answer can be used too.